# Are Turkey Black Sea beaches suitable for bathing in summer?

Tags: turkey, weather-and-climate, beaches

In June-July, it is possible I take a short trip to the north of Turkey. I'd like to know if their beaches worth a visit or not. Specifically, I'd like to know if:

1. Weather is appropriate for bathing (not raining, not low temperatures)
2. Water temperature is not too low
3. Water quality is good
4. Beaches are clean (not too much rubbish)

I have been to the Mediterranean coast of Turkey and the beaches I found in summer were nice and well mantained, I'd like to know if this also happens in the north of the country.

Comment: The Turkish Black Sea Coast is definitely worth a trip. But you don't go there for the beaches. If you are interested in beaches go to the mediterranean coast.

Comment: Clouds and rain are quite common in that area.

Comment: To answer both of you at once, I'd like to visit the Black Sea coast, but my partner prefers to stay in beaches. So the idea is to be sure that she's going to have some relax time in beaches. If not, we will choose another destination.

Comment: Then I would pick another destination. Or visit the Black Sea first and spend some days at the Mediterranean coast after that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although there are quite a few nice beaches along the Black Sea coastline, it's not particularly suitable for a vacation that's beach oriented.
The weather will definitely be fine, you shouldn't worry about the temperature. Nor should you worry about the water being too cold either. However there are still a couple of peculiarities that make the northern parts not usually preferred for tourists looking for a beach oriented vacation:

The humidity might be overwhelming in hot days if you aren't used to it, and depending on the particular city or town you visit, the rainfall might be a little too frequent than you'd like... Especially on the eastern parts. And as downhald put it, the Black Sea coasts usually deepen very quickly, which is fine, but for people who are into enjoying the shallow waters this will definitely be a turn-off. Plus, when there are strong winds, the quickly deepening seashore combined with the characteristically high and strong waves make it quite dangerous to swim. So you'll have to stay out of water if there are strong winds.

All those factors make the southern shores the preferred travel location for people who want to spend their vacations in beaches. If that's the case, you should stick to the southern or western shores.

That being said, the northern coastline has an amazing natural beauty if you're looking for a vacation combining both beaches and [nature trips](http://turkey.com/karadeniz-regions/turkish-scotland-plateaus-blacksea/), [cave exploration](http://www.academia.edu/6548923/The_caves_of_Sofular_and_Cayirkoy_Black_Sea_Coast_Turkey), [historical sightseeing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumela_Monastery), etc. In that case, you'll definitely love it.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. Apart from a few places in Istanbul (mainly around [Kilyos](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293974-i368-k5619910-Kilyos_beach-Istanbul.html) and [Şile](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293974-i368-k8315519-Agva_Sile_for_a_beach_getaway-Istanbul.html)) people don't go swimming on the shores of Black Sea in Turkey. The main problem is that it's pretty dangerous there as the waves can be strong and the sea gets deep very quickly once you're off the shore for a few meters. On top of that, although the weather is usually not cold during the summer months, it's [rainy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Sea_Region) most of the time, which might spoil your day.